# Changing part of HTML page via JSP, without changing other dynamic parts

Tags: html, spring, jsp, servlets

I have a web page, written in jsp and handled by spring servlet. This page has a static part(header, footer, & everything related to template) with two dynamic parts, one dependent to another.

I know how to fill dynamic part 1. But when user does something in part 1 which leads to filling part 2, controller has to send a new request to server and DB in order to get data for that part. I'm not loading whole data at once, since it would be inefficient- and page reloads. part 1 will be lost and jsp variables wont stay filled by their last value.

Is there anyway to pass data from last response to the new response, or any other method to let controller of part 2 have data to fill part 1?
Any answer would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are "many" ways... please read further/investigate ["ajax"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) and also maybe ["partial rendering jsp"](https://www.google.com/search?q=partial+rendering+jsp)

Comment: @xerx593 thanks for your answer. I searched about partial rendering, but from what I learned, it is used to render some parts of page from an external page. My problem is that I want a dynamic part to be triggered by....let's say, clicking a button in another part of the page. and in order to do that I need to send a request to server to fetch data, which leads to losing other dynamic parts which where already populated.

Comment: ..then you start (from the client side ..via js... or some higher lvl. framework...e.g. "onclick") an HTTP-Request to a/your server ..and when request successfully fulfills, you populate (again client sided) the relevant parts of your document... (with data from the newest response;) ..this you can refer to as "ajax" .. then.